# Qt - What is the regular widget equivalent of QDockWidget::toggleViewAction

Tags: c++, qt, widget

`QDockWidget::toggleViewAction()` can be used to hide/show each dockable widget. If I am just showing different widgets via `QWidget::setVisible()` then is there an equivalent function to toggle visibility or do I have to implement that myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent of a `QDockWidget::toggleViewAction()` for a `QWidget`, you will have to implement that yourself.